# Get the positions of the substrings before replacing

Tags: javascript, string, replace

If i have the string `foo bar foo baz foo` and i want to replace `foo` with `abcd`, i want to get the offsets of the replaced occurences in the string (`[0, 8, 16]` in this example). Ho do i get this positions?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean *before* replacing or after?  If you really mean *after* then the offsets would be `[0, 9, 18]`...

Comment: @maerics: thanks, i fixed it. But converting `[0, 8, 16]` to `[0, 9, 18]` is not a big challange :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var getPositions = function(str, sub) {
  var arr=[], idx=-1;
  while ((idx=str.indexOf(sub,idx+1)) > -1) {
    arr.push(idx);
  }
  return arr;
};

getPositions('foo bar foo baz foo', 'foo'); // => [0, 8, 16]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding what you're after, this should work for you

```
var getPositions = function (find, str) {
    var arr = [],
        pos = 0,
        flen = find.length,
        len = str.length, i;

    while (pos < len) {
        i = str.indexOf(find, pos);

        if (i !== -1) {
            arr.push(i);
            pos = i + flen;
        } else {
            return arr.length ? arr : false;
        }
    }
    return arr.length ? arr : false;
};
```

Then call it like `getPositions("foo", whateverString);`

http://jsfiddle.net/pyVaQ/

Answer (score 2):

Would you consider using regex? This way you wouldn't need to mess around with the overhead of finding the locations of the foo parts.  If you absolutely need the positions, this solution is not for you.

```
var str = 'foo bar foo baz foo';
str = str.replace(/foo/g,'abcd');
alert(str);
```

Comment: Not trying to rain on your parade, but the OP explicitly stated they want to "Get the positions of the substrings after replacing"

Comment: Yes, i want to get the positions :)

Comment: squidbe, you do a good job of not trying to rain on parades, thanks condensating retort.